# Selecting Values From Same Row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take the value of two table cell inputs and then multiply them into the last value input on the same row. I need to use class selectors as these rows can be added or deleted by the user as well. For example, in row 1 I want "cell 2 * cell 3 = cell 4" in row 1.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".p-cell, .s-cell", function() {
  var val1 = $(".p-cell").val();
  var val2 = $(".p-cell").next(".s-cell").val();
  var total = val1 * val2;
  $(".s-cell").next(".w-cell").val(total).trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="a-cell" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="p-cell" maxlength="2" value="0" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="s-cell" maxlength="2" value="1" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" class="w-cell" maxlength="3" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest` to find the parent `tr`, then go down the DOM with `find` to get the actual `td`s and values.

```
$(document).on("change", ".p-cell, .s-cell", function () {
    var _parent = $(this).closest("tr");
    var val1 = _parent.find(".p-cell").val();
    var val2 = _parent.find(".s-cell").val();
    var total = val1 * val2;
    _parent.find(".w-cell").val(total).trigger("input");
});
```